# How can I solve this issue of the Hanoi Tower without using recursive?

Tags: javascript, c, algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I tried to solve the tower of Hanoi with non-recursive, but an error occurred. Could you give me a favor? If possible, I want to know the solution by javascript.

This is my code with an error:

```
const hanoi = (n) => {
  const sign = ["a", "b", "c"];
  const path = [];
  let beforePile = 0;
  while (n--) {
    const nextPile = 1 + ((n + 1) % 2);
    path.push([0, nextPile]);
    const tmp = path;
    for (let i = 0; i < tmp.length - 1; i++)
      path.push([(path[i][0] + beforePile) % 3, (path[i][1] + beforePile) % 3]);
    beforePile = nextPile;
  }
  path.forEach((i) => {
    console.log(sign[i[0]] + " -> " + sign[i[1]]);
  });
};

hanoi(3);
```

( 'a' : start,  'c': destination )

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-tower-of-hanoi/

Comment: There are programming languages (Erlang) in which recursion is the primary iteration mechanism. "Main issue to cause a huge damage" is not accurate. The Hanoi problem is *inherently* recursive, so you can either use the recursion facility built into your programming language or you can do it yourself with your own stack implementation, but both approaches will be doing pretty much the same thing.

Comment: as an edit to my comment, that iterative trick is pretty clever.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a look on the paths of this problem, it has a rule.
In order to move n of pegs from 'a' to 'c', move n-1 of pegs from 'a' to 'b' then move a peg from 'a' to 'c'. Then move n-1 of pegs from 'b' to 'c'. So the paths between moving 'a' to 'b' and moving 'b' to 'c' is very similar. But all of the alphabets only differ 1 distance.
This is the key, i think.

```
const hanoi = (n) => {
  const sign = ["a", "b", "c"];
  const path = [];
  let beforePile = 0;
  while (n--) {
    const nextPile = 1 + ((n + 1) % 2);
    path.push([0, nextPile]);
    const tmp = path.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < tmp - 1; i++)
      path.push([(path[i][0] + beforePile) % 3, (path[i][1] + beforePile) % 3]);
    beforePile = nextPile;
  }
  path.forEach((i) => {
    console.log(sign[i[0]] + " -> " + sign[i[1]]);
  });
};

hanoi(3);
```